# Unable to load stock firmware (US Cellular)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, device-firmware, odin

My phone has gone into emergency recover and I've tried to recover it by flashing it with both "Odin" and the samsung "SimpleUpgradeTool" but it has failed everytime I've tried it.

I have the SCH-530 from US Cellular and am unsure on what to try next.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

The following is the ouput message from Odin ---

```
<ID:0/003> Odin v.3 engine (ID:3)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> recovery.img
<ID:0/003> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/003> cache.img
<ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```